# Featuretools deep feature synthesis doesn't generate features

Tags: pandas, featuretools

I'm using 3 datasets to create EntitySet using featuretools and use deep feature synthesis to generate additional features:

```
entity_set = ft.EntitySet("basketball_players")
entity_set.add_dataframe(dataframe_name="player_data",
                 dataframe=player_data,
                 index='name'
                 )

entity_set.add_dataframe(dataframe_name="players",
                 dataframe=players,
                 index='name'
                 )

entity_set.add_dataframe(dataframe_name="season_stats",
                 dataframe=season_stats,
                 index='name'
                 )

feature_matrix, features = ft.dfs(target_dataframe_name="season_stats",
                                  entityset=entity_set,
                                  max_depth = 3
                                  )
```

However, when I do `feature_matrix.columns`, I don't see that any new features were generated. I checked the [documentation](https://featuretools.alteryx.com/en/stable/generated/featuretools.dfs.html), and it is not necessary to add explicitly add trans_primitives and agg_primitives: there are

```
trans_primitives (list[str or TransformPrimitive], optional) –

List of Transform Feature functions to apply.

Default: [“day”, “year”, “month”, “weekday”, “haversine”, “num_words”, “num_characters”]
```

and

```
 agg_primitives (list[str or AggregationPrimitive], optional) –

List of Aggregation Feature types to apply.

Default: [“sum”, “std”, “max”, “skew”, “min”, “mean”, “count”, “percent_true”, “num_unique”, “mode”]
```

So new features should be generated anyway. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You did not define relationships between dataframes in your `entity_set`, I believe it is necessary to perform the `dfs`, no?

Comment: I don't have one-to-many relations between my dataframes. That's why I haven't done it.

Comment: Without relationships you will not get any aggregation features as the relationship are are necessary to determine how values should be aggregated. If the transform primitives you have selected (or the default primitives) cannot be applied to the types of columns you have in your `target_dataframe` you will not get any transform features either.